# BigQuery groupby, add row with count of 0 for groupby variable if no rows found

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

New to bigquery and have a problem that I think is broadly applicable to a lot of different group by / data manipulation problems. Any help is greatly appreciated! I run the following query which groups by team, game and by zone, and returns the count for each:

```
SELECT
  rebounds.team_id,
  rebounds.game_id,
  CASE
    WHEN distance < 4 THEN 'zone1'
    WHEN NOT some_bool THEN 'zone2'
    WHEN distance >= 4 and distance2 < 12 THEN 'zone3'
    WHEN some_bool AND distance >= 4 THEN 'zone4'
  END AS this_zone,
  COUNT(*) AS my_count
FROM t1
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

And I get the following table (showing for a single game_id / team_id combination for simplicity to emphasize the question):

```
team_id game_id this_zone my_count
     12      15     zone1        5
     12      15     zone2        3
```

In the example above, there were no observations that met the criteria for zone3, and as a result the table only returned two rows for this game_id + team_id combination. However, I would like to have a 3rd row, so that the table looks like this:

```
team_id game_id this_zone my_count
     12      15     zone1        5
     12      15     zone2        3
     12      15     zone3        2
     12      15     zone4        0
```

Is this possible, to specify one of the groupby variables (in this case `this_zone`), and have bigquery create a row with count 0 if the count is zero?

**EDIT**: I've updated the CASE WHEN to more accurately reflect the complexity of how the zones are created. In short, they rely on two different numerical values (distance and distance2 in this example), as well as a boolean value (some_bool)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT team_id, game_id, this_zone, IFNULL(my_count, 0) AS my_count
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    rebounds.team_id,
    rebounds.game_id, 
    this_zone
  FROM t1, UNNEST(['zone1', 'zone2', 'zone3', 'zone4']) this_zone
) A 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    rebounds.team_id,
    rebounds.game_id,
    CASE
      WHEN distance < 4 THEN 'zone1'
      WHEN NOT some_bool THEN 'zone2'
      WHEN distance >= 4 AND distance2 < 12 THEN 'zone3'
      WHEN some_bool AND distance >= 4 THEN 'zone4'
    END AS this_zone,
    COUNT(*) AS my_count
  FROM t1
  GROUP BY 1,2,3
) B
USING (team_id, game_id, this_zone)
```

Above is generic enough and has no dependency on how complex or not your logic - you just generate all expected rows (sub-query A) and left join it on your original query - that's all!

Comment: accepting this as the answer because it is a bit easier for me to understand than the other posted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Joining with a calendar table approach should work here:

```
WITH zones AS (
    SELECT 'zone1' AS zone UNION ALL
    SELECT 'zone2' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'zone3' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'zone4'
)

SELECT
    t.team_id,
    t.game_id,
    z.zone AS this_zone,
    COALESCE(COUNT(t2.game_id), 0) AS my_count
FROM zones z
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT team_id, game_id FROM t1) t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT team_id, game_id,
        CASE WHEN distance < 4 THEN 'zone1'
             WHEN NOT some_bool THEN 'zone2'
             WHEN distance >= 4 and distance2 < 12 THEN 'zone3'
             WHEN some_bool AND distance >= 4 THEN 'zone4'
        END AS this_zone
    FROM t1
) t2
    ON t2.team_id = t1.team_id AND
       t2.game_id = t1.game_id AND
       t2.this_zone = z.zone
GROUP BY
    t1.team_id,
    t1.game_id,
    z.zone
ORDER BY
    t1.team_id,
    t1.game_id,
    z.zone;
```

Comment: Thank you for this. 

However, it seems like I simplified my example too much. the criteria that creates the different zones are slightly more complex than 0 - 4, 4 - 8, 8 - 12, and I cannot use the >= d_low and < d_high approach in my actual problem.

Comment: Then it sounds like you need to edit your question now :-)

Comment: @Canovice I updated my answer.  The standard way of handling this is to use two calendar tables, one for all teams/games and the other for all zones.